# What is the use of this phrase "..there is a case to be made that.."?

Tags: phrases, history

Can anybody help me describe this phrase ? i don't understand what the author mean.

Context

*Zimmermann dreamed of changing the world. And he would. Only not quite in the way he intended. Indeed, there is a case to be made that Arthur Zimmermann was one of the most destructive individuals of the 20th century.*

Source: History of the world by Andrew Marr - Episode 7

Answer (score 5):

"There is a case to be made that" means, roughly, "One can argue that".

You can basically ignore it in this context without losing anything.

The verbal idiom "to make a case that/for" means to argue for a specific proposition or action. I know this because I am a native speaker.

I am not sure of the etymology, but [this site](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+a+case+for) suggests that it was used in legal contexts before non-legal contexts. It probably has its ultimate root in the Latin *cadere*, meaning "to fall" (as noted by @deadrat in the comment below).

Comment: The word *case* is interesting.  It's actually two words -- one from the Latin *capere* (to take) meaning a container and one from the Latin *cadere* (to fall) meaning circumstances or matters under consideration.  So "to make a case" is to justify the conclusion about some matter.  If you've got the time, perhaps you could elaborate in your answer.  In any case, I've upvoted for noting that it's an aside, essentially a hedge, that doesn't affect the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Thanks you! It's very wise, "There is a case to be made" =  "There is a conclusion that" is very well fit for the situation.